# Выгрузка данных из PHP в Google Spreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, google-spreadsheet

На сайте реализована выгрузка данных в CSV. В виде входящих данных многомерный массив. Как реализовать выгрузку этих данных на Google Drive в файл excel?

Подозреваю, что ответ совсем не простой. Хочу понимать хотя бы последовательность действий, с чего начать. Все мои поиски по API пока не дали понимания.

Comment: Рекомендую описать что именно Вы искали, нашли и чем это не подошло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите на официальную документацию: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Там сразу же пример авторизации и пример получения данных с документа по конкретному ID. Я бы посоветовал брать этот API и пробовать, пробовать и пробовать. Сначала читать, потом писать, потом загружать. Там не все супер просто, но разобраться можно

Если у вас не много документов и их выгрузка происходит не часто, то возможно вам достаточно будет просто использовать "Файл - Импорт - Загрузить файл с компьютера" в ручном режиме. Не очень красиво, но работать точно будет )

Еще один вариант - выкладывать просто csv/Excel куда-нибудь в доступ (*.Диск и т.п. или к себе на сайт), современные браузеры умеют сразу показывать документ из коробки или через плагины/дополнения